# Making Sound Button stop after start

Tags: android, button, audio

I need a button that will start when pressed and stop when pressed again.  Otherwise I have overlapping sounds.  Can any of you assist me with the code please? Below is what I currently have and can't get the button to stop when clicked again so currently it is just playing and stops when the sound is done causing sounds to overlap. Getting one to stop when another is pressed would also be ideal but I don't have a clue how to easily incorporate this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_boardone);

    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(BoardoneActivity.this, R.raw.mouse_laughter);  
            mp.start();

        }
    });

    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(BoardoneActivity.this, R.raw.evil_laugh);  
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 3):

Dont use two objects of Media Player. Bleow is the snippet of methods from my project. If any error let me know.

```
private MediaPlayerManager mRecordingPlayer = null;



        private void initAudioPlayer(){
        if(mRecordingPlayer == null){
            mRecordingPlayer = new MediaPlayerManager();

        }
    }


        private void playMusic(int position){
        initAudioPlayer();
        mRecordingPlayer.resetPlayer();
        mRecordingPlayer.setupPlayback("your reasource");
        mRecordingPlayer.startPlaying();
    }

       private void stopPlaying(){
        initAudioPlayer();
        if(mRecordingPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mRecordingPlayer.pausePlaying();

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        clearAudioPlayer();
        super.onPause();
    }


    private void clearAudioPlayer(){
        if(mRecordingPlayer != null ){
            mRecordingPlayer.resetPlayer();
        }
    }


   @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
            if(on){
                playMusic("play music");
                ((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(true);
            }else{
                stopPlaying();
            }

    }
```

Comment: Hi There Thank you for the replies, I've tried your method Innocent, not to sure Ranjith about the recording. I am creating a soundboard.  I tried playing around with the code but still nothing.  Would you be able to use my code to present an example.  I've spent hours and still can't figure this out and there is nothing on this on Youtube.  Thank you for the help guys.  I'm really hoping one of you cn make this work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with below code.

```
mPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.pause();
                        mPlayPause.setText("Play");
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.start();
                        mPlayPause.setText("Pause");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```